# Looping a Json object in map.arc()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dictionary, d3.js

i am using http://jsbin.com/nutawiboci/1/edit?html,output to show the location of the origin and destination coordinate and draw an arc between them. so i modified the map.arc() to loop through a given origin and destination coordinate:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

      var origin_long  = data[i][0][0]; 
      var origin_lat   = data[i][0][1]; 

      var destination_long = data[i][1][0]; 
      var destination_lat  = data[i][1][1]; 



        map.arc([
          {
            origin: {
                latitude: origin_lat,
                longitude: origin_long
            },
            destination: {
                latitude: destination_lat,
                longitude: destination_long
            }
          }
          ], {strokeWidth: 2});
    };
```

This actually works, but it only draws the last(from the loop) since it destroys the previous arcs before drawing the next. i just don't know how to iterate in the map.arc(). i want the loop to return something like this:

```
        map.arc([
          {
            origin: {
                latitude: 43.445,
                longitude: 83.435345
            },
            destination: {
                latitude: 324.2323,
                longitude: -6
            }
          }, 
          {
            origin: {
                latitude: -53.445,
                longitude: 333.4345
            },
            destination: {
                latitude: -24.2323,
                longitude: 46.454
            }
          }, 
          {
            origin: {
                latitude: 53.045,
                longitude: 663.4345
            },
            destination: {
                latitude: -94.2323,
                longitude: 996.4454
            }
          }
          ], {strokeWidth: 2});
```

any other way than looping it is also appreciated, i just want it working this way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting values in your loop..try pushing each co-ordinate into a temporary array first and then assign the temporary array to `map arc` try something like:

```
 var temp = []
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

  var origin_long  = data[i][0][0]; 
  var origin_lat   = data[i][0][1]; 

  var destination_long = data[i][1][0]; 
  var destination_lat  = data[i][1][1]; 

   var prepare  = 
        {origin: {
            latitude: origin_lat,
            longitude: origin_long
        },
        destination: {
            latitude: destination_lat,
            longitude: destination_long

      }};
  temp.push(prepare);
};

map.arc(temp,{strokeWidth: 2})
```